# pandas always cast column to object even if column contains only integer

Tags: python, pandas, types

I try this one:

```
pd.DataFrame(numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 'a', 'b']]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).dtypes

a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

but in next case when all columns contain only integer values I got correct types of columns

```
pd.DataFrame(numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).dtypes
a    int64
b    int64
c    int64
dtype: object
```

why pandas doesn't cast to int64 a,b columns in first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy ndarray can only have one data type, and it uses the most general one that can store all the different value types. So the ndarray `numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 'a', 'b']]` is of type Object, because it has to store both ints and strings. When converting it to a dataframe Pandas uses that type for all columns.

If you want to have different dtypes for different columns, you can create the dataframe from several separate ndarrays, for example

```
numpy.array([1, 2, 3]),
numpy.array([4, 5, 6]),
numpy.array([7, 'a', 'b'])
```

or convert columns after the creation with something like [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array can not contain different dtypes.

you can easily convert String to numeric if the column contains only numeric data by this method:

```
df.a = pd.to_numeric(df.a)   # a is the column name
```